# How do you return a string message from a method without the use of exceptions

Tags: c#

```cs
class Device
{
public void AssignDevice(string playerName)
        {
            if (IsAssigned())
            {
                string message = "This device is already assinged to a player";
                MessageBox.Show(message);
            }
            else
            {
                this.playerName = playerName;
            }
        }
}
```

im trying to make a method that returns a string in a messageBox if it is true without the use of exceptions. is there any suggestions?
this is made in winforms.

Comment: Could you be more clear? Since returning means actually returning a value to the method that calls the called method. What are you exactly trying to achieve? Do you want a dialog messagebox, where someone types something in?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm concerned you should be able to get the response without working with Exceptions.

```
MessageBox.Show(message);    
if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
{
    // Closes the parent form.
    this.Close();
}
```

Or just check out the microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.messagebox?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you can just return some string, e.g. either *error message* or `null` when operation succeeds:

```
// return error message or null on success
public string AssignDevice(string playerName) {
   if (IsAssigned()) {
     string message = "This device is already assigned to a player";
     
     MessageBox.Show(message);

     return message; 
   }
   else
     this.playerName = playerName;
   
   return message;
}
```

Or using `Try` pattern:

```
// return true on success, false of error, message - error message  
public bool TryAssignDevice(string playerName, out string message) {
   string message = null;

   if (IsAssigned()) {
     message = "This device is already assigned to a player";

     return false; 
   }
   else
     this.playerName = playerName;
   
   return true;
}
```

usage

```
if (!TryAssignDevice(playerName, out var errorMessage)) {
  MessageBox.Show(errorMessage); 
}
```

The *drawback* of such approach (no exception but some return value(s)) is that the return can be *easily ingored*.